# mapbox ruby on rails assets.precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, mapbox, precompile

This is more of an answer to a problem more than a it is a question. I kept getting this error after I added the mapbox gem to my Ruby on Rails project:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( icons-ffffff.png )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server
```

I would add the suggestions but another suggestion/error would pop up with a different string after the "%w( icons-..." . I finally found the solution to be in this link https://github.com/aai/mapbox-rails/issues/11

Just add this to your application.rb file.

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( icons-*.png )
```

It worked for me. My app works now. Hope this helps someone